# wordpress blog title url

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I'm trying to make my blog titles link to the full post from the preview area so the title should have the same function as the read more button. The blogs are in a masonry layout and I'm using a themeforest theme.

This is the blog page.

I believe this to be the php code that controls the layout - hope it helps.

Sorry php newbie here.

I have tried using `<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><h5 class="post-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h5></a>';` but all this did was generate a broken url containing '.get_permalink().'" in it.

Thank you

```
                    <?php if ( '' != get_the_title() ): ?>
        <h5 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if (has_post_format('link')): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $nz_link_url; ?>" title="<?php echo __("Go to", TEMPNAME).' '.$nz_link_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo __("Read more", TEMPNAME); ?><span class="icon-arrow-right9"></span></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo __("Read more about", TEMPNAME).' '.get_the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo __("Read more", TEMPNAME); ?><span class="icon-arrow-right9"></span></a>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Output the entire while loop please.

Comment: All done sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to wrap the h5 title in an anchor tag `<a>` on line 37 of your snippet. The specific code to change is:

### New Answer

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>">
    <h5 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
</a>
```

or from you code, try:

```
<a href="<?php echo $nz_link_url; ?>" title="<?php echo __("Go to", TEMPNAME).' '.$nz_link_url; ?>">
    <h5 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
</a>
```

### Old Answer

```
if ( '' != get_the_title() ){
    $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><h5 class="post-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h5></a>';
}
```

You may have to update your CSS to reflect the anchor tag in front of the H5

**Full Code**

```
 while($recent_posts->have_posts()) : $recent_posts->the_post();

                $output .= '<div class="post format-'.get_post_format().'" data-grid="ninzio_01">';

                    $output .= '<div class="post-wrap nz-clearfix">';

                        if (get_post_format() == 'image') {
                            $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
                            $nz_image_url = isset($values["image_url"][0]) ? $values["image_url"][0] : "";

                            if (!empty($nz_image_url)) {
                                $output .='<a class="nz-more" href="'.get_permalink().'">';
                                    $output .= '<div class="nz-thumbnail">';
                                        $output .= '<img src="'.$nz_image_url.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'">';
                                        $output .= '<div class="ninzio-overlay"></div>';
                                        $output .= '<div class="post-date"><span>'.get_the_date("d").'</span><span>'.get_the_date("M").'</span></div>';
                                    $output .='</div>';
                                $output .='</a>';
                            }

                        } else {
                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                $output .='<a class="nz-more" href="'.get_permalink().'">';
                                    $output .= '<div class="nz-thumbnail">';
                                        $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size );
                                        $output .= '<div class="ninzio-overlay"></div>';
                                        $output .= '<div class="post-date"><span>'.get_the_date("d").'</span><span>'.get_the_date("M").'</span></div>';
                                    $output .='</div>';
                                $output .='</a>';
                            }
                        }



                        $output .= '<div class="post-body">';

                                if ( '' != get_the_title() ){
                                    $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><h5 class="post-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h5></a>';
                                }

                                if ($excerpt == "true") {
                                    $output .= '<div class="post-excerpt">'.nz_excerpt(95).'</div>';
                                }

                                $output .='<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.__("Read more about", TEMPNAME).' '.get_the_title().'" rel="bookmark">'.__("Read more", TEMPNAME).' <span class="icon-arrow-right9"></span></a>';

                        $output .= '</div>';

                    $output .= '</div>';

                $output .= '</div>';
```

Comment: replaced the while loop with your modified one, but I can't seem to get it to work for some reason... I don't see why it wouldn't work, everything you said made sense lol :/

Comment: This is the answer so if this answer doesn't work then you have edited the wrong file.  Try `single.php`

Comment: This is everything that is inside my single.php  <?php

 get_header();
  get_template_part('/includes/blog/content-blog-header');
  get_template_part('/includes/blog/content-blog-body');
 get_footer(); 

?>

I have checked both those files and cannot find a reference to the blog post-title class. the only place i could find it in was shortcodes.php which is what i posted here. Thanks

Comment: @Nicole as McNab has pointed out, you are probably just editing the wrong file and confusing yourself now. If the code change in **page.php** is not successful, trying altering the code in **archive.php**.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will accept the answer just because I know it is correct, although it did not work for me. :)

 Thanks for your time.

Comment: I finally found where this is, but  I am unable to post it in the comments so I will edit, if you can still have a quick look please.

Comment: Thanks, it has now made the title into a url, but it's failing to get the permalink so clicking on any of the titles will just take me to the news page which is the preview. Please try it here to see what I mean http://uwinat.o2clite.com/news/  Thanks

Comment: Try `<a href="<?php echo $nz_link_url; ?>" title="<?php echo __("Go to", TEMPNAME).' '.$nz_link_url; ?>">
    <h5 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
</a>`

Comment: Tried and still the same result, it is linking to the news page so not picking up the post's permalink. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91010/discussion-between-ham-sandwich-and-nicole).